# List<T>.AsReadOnly() vs IReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, generics, collections

`List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface and provides the `AsReadOnly()` method which returns `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (which in turn implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`).

What is the usage/reason for `AsReadyOnly()`? Its existence smells of one or two edge cases where just returning the list as `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is just not good enough.

At first I though it may be to prevent casting the cost-ness away but it looks like you can do that with `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`'s `Items` accessor.

BTW. The documentation for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` type reads

> Provides the base class for a generic read-only collection.

which, in my head, conflicts with having a constructor described as

> Initializes a new instance of the (...) class that is a read-only wrapper around the specified list.

**Update:**
I did not see that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`'s `Items` is protected.

Comment: I prefer `.ToArray()`.  Simpler IMO!

Comment: @KierenJohnstone probably slower, too.

Comment: `.ToArray()` creates an entirely new array so it's slower, and the array is mutable, meaning, any of its elements can be changed.
`.AsReadOnly()` is faster, and consumers can't mutate it by changing individual elements. It does change when the original list is changed though.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you just return an actual `List<T>` as an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, then the caller can always just cast it back, and then modify the list as they please. Conversely, calling `AsReadOnly()` creates a read-only wrapper of the list, which consumers can't update.

Note that the read-only wrapper will reflect changes made to the underlying list, so code with access to the original list can still update it with the knowledge that any consumers of the read-only version will see those changes.

Comment: But I can cast back `AsReadOnly().Items`, can't I?

Comment: @Tymek You cannot: `AsReadOnly()` creates a new, non-`List<T>` class, which has no public methods that permit mutation of the underlying list. (`Items` is *`protected`*, so random consumers can't access it.)

Comment: Items is not the original list, you can't change the original list.

Comment: @Steven `Items` is the original list, but I only now noticed that it's protected. Doh!

Comment: Also note that the List<T>.AsReadOnly() method exists since .NET 2.0 while the IReadOnlyCollection interface is new in .NET 4.5. So the API might overlap a bit here, but AsReadOnly is still useful.

Comment: @Tymek, the original list? Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Steven yes, `AsReadonly` always returned `ReadonlyCollection<T>` since .NET 2.0, just that `ReadonlyCollection<T>` implemented `IReadonlyCollection<T>` recently.

Comment: If someone is not above casting `IReadOnlyList<T>` to `List<T>`, they are not above using reflection to get private `list` field of `ReadOnlyCollection`. There is no 100% protection. I have do so few times in past to avoid bugs in libraries.

Answer (score 30):

First of all it's not that `AsReadOnly()` was added because `IReadOnlyList<T>` isn't good enough -- `IReadOnlyList<T>` is only available starting with .NET 4.5 while `AsReadOnly()` method exists since .NET 2.

More importantly: `AsReadOnly()` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` serve very different purposes.

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is meant for implementing object models, for example things like `Dictionary<K,V>.Keys` and `Dictionary<K,V>.Values`. This is for scenarios where consumers shouldn't be able to change the contents while the producer can. It works in tandem with `Collection<T>` which provides hooks for the owner to validate changes or perform side effects when items get added.

`IReadOnlyList<T>` on the other hand is simply an interface that provides a read-only view of the collection. Methods can use it in order to say "I need a random access collection but I don't need to be able to modify it". For example, a `BinarySearch` method might look like this:

```
public int BinarySearch<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list, int start, int length);
```

In order to make this method useful, it's required to be able to pass in any List. Forcing to create wrapper collections would be prohibitively expensive.